# WinForms field not updating

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 boolean fields, two for NumberUpAndDown Controls for an event in which  their value is changed and the third control for my textbox which should change based on if the textbox is empty or not (i coded this into my bol method).

The problem is none of my boolean fields are changing when i change my NumerUpAndUp Controls or my textbox control.

I am expecting all 3 fields to change to `true` when i input values in my textbox and my NumberUpandDown controls. This should then also mean my label1 control should change to true.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ApplicationForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public bool NumeratorCheck;
        public bool DenominatorCheck;
        public bool CommentCheck;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bol();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void numericUpDownNumerator_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            NumeratorCheck = true;
        }

        private void numericUpDownDenominator_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DenominatorCheck = true;
        }

        private void bol()
        {

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxComments.Text))
            {
                CommentCheck = true;
                label1.Text = "true";
            }
           else
            {
                CommentCheck = false;
                label1.Text = "false";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `bol` runs **only** once. Not every time you edit the textbox. Have a read of the duplicate and try and implement what it suggests.

Comment: But you call `bol()` only once at the creation of the form, but not when the values of the numupdowns or the textbox changes.